Reference to get quickly to modern discrete probability theory
I've had some formal training in Analysis - Functional Analysis, Basic Operator Algebra - and I've started working on probability - specifically Combinatorial Statistical Mechanics and Spin-Glasses. Are there any modern books in probability that goes through the foundation of probability theory including Martingales and Brownian Motion in a relatively short exposition. Since I'm going to be dealing with mainly discrete model for the foreseeable future, I would love to know if there are encyclopedic yet concise resources for the same.

"encyclopedic yet concise" hmm...

I think this is a reasonable question. Different books have different emphases and it is reasonable to ask which texts are best suited to a given research area

You ask about a reference for "discrete" models, but one of the two topics you mention is Brownian motion, which is hardly discrete. Anyway, Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples could be the sort of thing you're looking for. It's modern and readable - it's not exactly short, but perhaps it's about as short as it might reasonably be while covering the sort of topics you're asking about.

It’s a bit unclear exactly what kind of reference you’re asking for, but Grimmett and Stirzaker’s Probability and Random Processes is a very nice introduction in my view.
Another possibility is Billingsley’s Probability and Measure. This latter recommendation is almost entirely focused on probability in discrete time.
